# Excel macro for cell fill in with one click based on dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fill a range of cells let's say A1:A5 with the value that is in a drop down list let's say in B1, by clicking once with the mouse in cells A1:A5. The way i want it to work is to first select the value that i want from the dropdown list and then click in in any of the cells from range A1:A5, and only the cell selected changes the value to the value from the dropdown list. And also when i change the value from the dropdown list the cells that were previously filled by clicking them  do not change automatically to the new value from drop down. Once clicked they remain to that value until clicked to another selected value.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: You need to use the selection_change event for the sheet   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange

Answer (score 0):

Add data validation to B1, under "Allow:" you pick "List", under "Source:" your values like: Value1,Value2,Value3... .. or of course a range..

Paste the following in sheet code(eg Sheet1(sheet1))

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A5")) Is Nothing Then
        Selection.Value = Range("B1").Value
        Range("B1").Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```